# How do i combine youtube,vimeo and dailymotion's search bars together

Tags: api, search, youtube, vimeo

How do i combine youtube,vimeo and dailymotion's search bars together so that i can make a universal search engine for video?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look at their API docs and figure out how to pull in all the data. Then you'd need your own (probably quite complex) sorting algorithm to mix the results up.

But step 1 should be pulling all the data in, check out the relevant links;
http://vimeo.com/api/docs/methods/vimeo.videos.search
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_category_keyword_browsing.html
http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First learn all the api that means how its work. There is only problem with page navigation. YouTube use page navigation by token and vimeo, dailymotion use numbers. Then use page navigation by 
Domain/search-keywork/youtube-token/numbers.

Comment: I have removed your dead link.

Answer (score -1):

Use curl_multi to do multiple search in parrallal, then you have to merge all results in same structure ....